# A subset $A \subset X$ is open if and only if $\forall p \in A, \exists U \in \mathcal{T}, p \in U \subset A$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Show that a subset $A \subset X$ is open if and only if for every $p \in A$, there exists an open set $U \subset X$ such that $p \in U \subset A$.

Here is my attempt.

> ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $A \subset X$ is open. By definition, for every $x \in A$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon} (x) \subset A$. But $B_{\epsilon} (x)$ is open, so set $U := B_{\epsilon} (x)$. Furthermore, $d(x,x) = 0 < \epsilon$, so $x \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$. Therefore, $x \in U \subset A$.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Conversely, suppose that for every $p \in A$, there exists an open set $U \subset X$ such that $p \in U \subset A$. Given $x \in A$, we choose $U_X \in \mathcal{T}$ with $x \in U_X$. Then
> $$
> A = \bigcup\limits_{x \in A} U_x.
> $$
> Indeed, if $x \in A$, we have $x \in U_x \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in A} U_x$. Conversely, for every $x \in A$, $U_x \subset A$, so $\bigcup\limits_{x \in A} U_x \subset A$. As each $U_x$ is open, and the arbitrary union of open sets is open, we have that $A$ is open.

How does this proof look?

Comment: For your forwards direction, you may wish to avoid balls with radii---the topological space $X$ doesn't have to be metrizable.

Comment: @prets This is an excellent point, thank you. Is the more general statement that for every $x \in A$, there exists an open set $U \owns x$ such that $U \subset A$?

Comment: Yes indeed---it's the theorem you're proving. Your forwards direction can be made much simpler, and then you're done: since $A$ is open, what happens if you take $U = A$?

Comment: That is a lot easier. Then the result is just immediate.